# Product of disjoint cycles in Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've got some permutations:

$\left( \begin{smallmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
 3 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 6 & 2 \end{smallmatrix} \right) $ and $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 3 & 2 & 1 & 5 & 4 & 6 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$

I've found the cycles to be: $(1,3,4)(2,5,6)(1,3)(2)(4,5)(6)$ but now I want to decompose this into product of disjoint cycles.

I have no idea how to do that. After I do that, I want to write them as a product of transposition. I've searched high and low for a good explanation on how to do this but none seems to help.

Comment: Understanding what's going on in the problem. That hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *two* separate permutations. $$\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 3 & 2 & 1 & 5 & 4 & 6 \end{smallmatrix} \right),\quad \text{ and }\quad\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 3 & 2 & 1 & 5 & 4 & 6 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$$

The first permutation, written as the product of disjoint cycles, is given by $$(1,3,4)(2,5,6)$$

The second, by $$(1,3)(2)(4,5)(6) = (1, 3)(4, 5)$$

To write a product of disjoint cycles as a product of transpositions, there are any number of ways to do so. One algorithm, for example, is used here: $$(a_1, a_2, a_3)(a_4, a_5, a_6, a_7) = (a_1, a_3)(a_1, a_2)(a_4, a_7)(a_4, a_6)(a_4, a_5)$$

Using that approach on your first permutation, we decompose $$(1,3,4)(2,5,6) = (1, 4)(1, 3)(2, 6)(2, 5)$$

Note that your second permutation, $(1,3)(2)(4,5)(6) = (1, 3)(4, 5)$, is already the product of transpositions.

One-easy-to-remember algorithm, which I'll apply to your first permutation, is as follows, $$(1, 3, 4)(2, 5, 6) = (1, 3)(3, 4)(2, 5)(5, 6)$$

---

Note: Do not be troubled that there are two correct decompositions here. You just need to know that composing any correct-but-non-unique decompositions will yield the same permutation you have prior to decomposing it into the product of transpositions.

Comment: So I am not expected to understand this algorithm in a normal abstract algebra class or..?

Comment: Yes, you'll want to know *at least one* algorithm. Look at the "easy to remember" algorithm I post immediately before the line break: $$(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5) = (a_1, a_2)(a_2, a_3)(a_3, a_4)(a_4, a_5)$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a decomposition into product of disjoint cycles and into product of transpositions
$$\left( \begin{smallmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
 3 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 6 & 2 \end{smallmatrix} \right)=(1\ 3\ 4)(2\ 5\ 6)=(1\ 4)(1\ 3)(2\ 6)(2\ 5) $$

Can you do the same for the second permutation?

Comment: $(13)(2)(45)(6)$? It's already decomposed?

Comment: Surely and notice that it's useless to write $(2)$ and $(6)$

Comment: I'm not fully understanding what I am doing. I'm just seeing a pattern and following it. I don't understand how these can be omitted as a result.